# Memtest86+ failing address, what does this mean?

Tags: ramdisk, memtest86+

My computer recently got a problem where whenever I turn on the computer I would see a blue screen telling me to remove disks or other medias. So I messed around and thought it was hopeless then I turned to the only solution I know of, to reinstall Windows. Now Windows doesn't even install or any Linux distro. I finally found memtest86+ and did it through a USB drive and Linux distro that included it. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my RAM?

```
Tst= 9 
pass= 1 
failing address= 000508708bc - 1288 . 0MB
Good= 62fb9344
Bad= 62fb934c
Err-Bits= 00000008
Count= 1
CPU= 0
```

Comment: Just that the RAM is not stable. Whether it degraded over time or is just due to a change of bios settings. In either case it may be fixable by adjusting RAM voltage (very slightly), changing to a lower speed eg 1333mhz instead of 1600mhz. Changing to different RAM timing values, or a different RAM profile (not XMP profile if it exists) in BIOS. Could also be CPU settings related. If you are confident to change these types of settings you may have luck, or may not. If these settings are new to you then some reading would be required.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Memtest wrote some memory.  Then it tried to read it back.  If things were good, it would have read a hexadecimal value of 62fb9344.  Instead, it got a hexadecimal value of 62fb934c.  Mathematically, 62fb934c - 62fb9344 = 8.  8 is a power of two.  (2 to the power of 3 is eight.)  Somewhere, the third bit from the end of a chunk of memory didn't work right.  Memtest doesn't report such problems for no reason, so let me repeat that critical conclusion: **your hardware didn't work right**.

Obviously, if you care about your data, or results of whatever this computer may be assigned to do, this *must* be rectified if the computer is going to continue to be used.

In some cases, you might have entirely good components, but have some corrosion.  You can try reseating the RAM.  (Take the RAM out.  Check for anything visibly not right (namely: corrosion).  Place it back in, right back in the same RAM slot that came from.)  That actually helps in some cases where oxidization leads to problems.  After doing that, re-test.

Note that if you have 1 good pass, that dosen't mean perfection.  Sometimes Memtest catches things on a later pass (more commonly in the first 3-4 passes).

Otherwise, it looks like you have bad hardware.  It could be your motherboard, or even your power supply (bad PSU), but most likely is a RAM stick.  Try removing one RAM stick at a time (unless you need to remove two at a time due to dual-channel limitations that some motherboards have).

Once it seems like you have have identified which RAM stick is bad, try placing that RAM stick in again, preferably in another slot, to help determine whether it is the RAM stick (more likely) or the motherboard slot (probably less likely).

Note: Please do not boot your computer in a way that may write to the disk.  (Booting off a bootable CD that is known to not write to the hard drive may be okay.)  Understand that with bad RAM, bad data may be written to the hard drive, which could cause data corruption (including filesystem corruption) that may cause even more problems even after fixing the bad RAM.  Treat this as urgent to minimize future problems (hopefully reducing those down to zero).

Comment: Holy smokes, thanks for the detailed and understandable answer for a noob like me. I'll follow the instructions and see where the problem lies. Thanks a lot man

Comment: I think there's basically zero chance that corrosion is at fault--there's no situation where only one bit goes through any given contact.  It's a bad memory cell.  I wouldn't play with voltages--at best you end up with a marginal machine that way, you can't count on it not failing again.  Find the bad stick, replace it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: I agree. The exception, of course, is if the OP has been trying to "performance tune" their system before by playing with the voltages and timings. In that case the tuning might have triggered the instability, and restoring the settings to safe values may fix it. But if memtest is still failing at settings that the hardware manufacturer considers normal, then the hardware is defective and should be replaced.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen If they were performance tuning they would know what to do--undo the latest change.  They wouldn't be here asking what the Memtest results mean.